# Run C# Console Application on Visual Studio Code Editor on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to create (from scratch) and run simple C# Console app in VSCode editor. ?
Can you please provide step-by-step instruction how I can do that?
What kind of files I must to include (except HelloWolrd.cs obviously)?
What kind of commands I must to execute?

Answer (score 14):

Navigate to the folder you want to create the console app in. In VSCode, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to open the terminal window or go to *View* and select *Integrated Terminal*. Now type the following below:

1. `dotnet new console`
2. `dotnet restore`
3. `dotnet run`

Comment: Short, sweet, basically native--but I had to install .NET Core SDK first. Found here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd .

Comment: Thanks for keeping it simple and to the point.  @arichards Thank you for the link.   When you install .NET Core SDK make sure to close your terminal/editor before running the dotnet commands in the answer above.

Answer (score 3):

The best way at this present time to create a console application is to create a DNX style Console Application.

I would advise that you download and install the [generator-aspnet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet) Yeoman generator and use that to generate a DNX Console application. Once you've got generator-aspnet installed, in your terminal/console app type `yo aspnet` and select `Console Application`.

Here's a thorough guide to creating a DNX Console application which will work with VS Code: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html

Comment: @e4c5 Done. Have updated the answer to provide the most important bit. Also, I feel as though my initial answer was entirely valid as creating a simple DNX Console application to be used with VS Code will likely never change in the future!

Comment: Thank, you. I have upvoted. I was just pointing out the stackoverflow policy.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to get a 'hello world' set up using visual studio code and c# on mac/osx.

the way I did it was as follows:

1. Install VS Code and the C# extension
2. Here (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) are instructions for installing dotnet core using brew:

   - Install OpenSSL

     ```
     brew update
     brew install openssl
     ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
     ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
     ```
   - Install dotnet core pkg: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827526
3. Create a folder somewhere and in that folder run `dotnet new`
4. Go into VS code and open the folder to get the project loaded
5. Open the terminal in that folder and run `dotnet run`

To create run as a task

- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then type task
- select the Task: Configure Task Runner option
- in the tasks.json file after the build task, add the following:

  ```
  {
      "taskName":"run",
      "args": [
          "${workspaceRoot}/project.json"
      ]
  }
  ```