# Code to generate templates

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just downloaded Visual Studio Code last night. What do I do so that Code will generate, say, a Console Application template?

I've read around the web so far I can't find anything telling me how to create a template.

Comment: Ok I downloaded Yeoman got a generator thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q: How do I create and run a new project?**
>
> A: VS Code doesn't include a traditional File > New Project dialog or
>   pre-installed project templates. You'll need to add additional
>   components and scaffolders depending on your development interests.
>   With scaffolding tools like Yeoman and the multitude of modules
>   available through the NPM package manager, you're sure to find
>   appropriate templates and tools to create your projects.

for details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview

and a question on SO: [Run C# Console Application on Visual Studio Code Editor on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005966/run-c-sharp-console-application-on-visual-studio-code-editor-on-windows)